# Sorting a std::list<myclass*> with using myclass::operator[](int i)

Tags: c++, list, std

I would like to sort my list std::list depending on the parameter. For example:

```
class myclass
{
    string name, surname;
public:
    myclass() {}
    ~myclass() {}
    string operator[](int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1: return name;
        case 2: return surname;
        }
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct compare
{
    int num;
    indirect_compare() {}
    indirect_compare(int i) : num(i) {}
    ~indirect_compare() {}
    bool operator()(T * lhs, T * rhs) { return (*lhs)[num] < (*rhs)[num]; }
};

list<myclass*> lst;  
int specified_by_user;  
cin >> specified_by_user;  

//later

lst.sort(compare<myclass>(specified_by_user));
```

It works fine for me but I'm not sure whether it's correct. When I added some message in constructor and destructor in structure compare, I saw that the constructor was called only once but the destructor was called for example 9 times and I have no ideas why it happened. I tried to debug this program to check it but I couldn't find the reason.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: The other constructors was probably the copy ctor. Did you monitor that one?

Comment: Compare's ctor and dtor is named indirect_compare. Does the example compile?  Also get rid of the no arguments ctor if it's invalid to use.

Comment: `not sure whether it's correct` looks correct to me, there are a few different ways to do it but yours isn't wrong

Comment: int num is not initialized, if there is a default constructor, then there should be a default value for it. Moreover you can define compare method as a member of your base class via using inheritence instead of template, which might make things easier for you. Additionally you can use lambda functions according to your need during sorting or you can add separated methods such that CompareByName, CompareBySurname, since it is better have an if check before sorting than entering in a switch block for each item of the list.

Comment: This is actually very interesting. I had no idea that the comparator was going to be copied like that. Have to keep that in mind and keep comparators as slim as possible. Upvoting on the strength of that realization.

Comment: It could be copy ctor indeed. I got rid of the no arguments ctor but it worked in the same way that is to say one ctor with argument and multiple dtors. I wouldn't like to create methods like CompareByName etc. because many of them works in the same way (comparing strings) and I wanted to simplify that. Thanks for help once again!

Comment: I added copy ctor and that was it indeed. Now the numbers of called ctors and dtors are equal. Thanks Sheph!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to move the switch from the operator[] to the comparison function object (maybe even use lambda instead). That would allow you to compare properties that are not of the same type. (e.g. if you add a member `int age;`

Also I would have a list of the things instead of a list of pointers to things. You might get the 1 constructor and multiple deletes problem because you're not careful enough with the pointers.

Something like this:

```
struct myclass
{
  string name;
  string surname;
};

template <typename T>
struct compare
{
  int num;
  compare() {}
  compare(int i) : num(i) {}
  ~compare() {}
  bool operator()(const T & lhs, const T & rhs) {
    switch(num)
    {
       case 1: return lhs->name < rhs->name;
       case 2: return lhs->surname < rhs->surname;
       default: throw std::logic_error();
    }
  }
};

list<myclass> lst;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! The idea is fine but I want to preserve members name and surname private and because I have more strings in my class I wouldn't like to create getter and setter for each member. That's why I used operator[].

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine. Your solution is a bit unusual, but if it works for you go for it! In the spirit of Mircea Baja I'd like to show you an alternative solution to your problem, just for inspiration:

```
if (specified_by_user) // sort by name
    lst.sort(auto [](auto const & a, auto const & b){ return a.name < b.name; });
else // sort by surname
    lst.sort(auto [](auto const & a, auto const & b){ return a.surname < b.surname; });
```

First, we move the decision by which field to sort out of your class and into the client code. Second, instead of defining a comparator struct, we pass lambdas into lst.sort(), which can be defined very concisely, inline in the function call itself.

This implies that the fields name and surname be public (so the lambdas can access them). If you'd like to keep them private, you can add getters to your class instead:

```
string const & get_name() const { return name; }
```

and change the lambdas slightly:

```
auto [](auto const & a, auto const & b){ return a.get_name() < b.get_name(); }
```

Comment: It's great but I would like to preserve members name and surname private and because I have more strings in my class I wouldn't like to create getter and setter for each member (especially that I would use them only in this case). The comparisons works in the same way so I tried to shorten my code. That's the reason why I used operator[].